# String cannot be input and skip to next prompt

Tags: java, string

The problem lies in the output. I get the expected output upto the contact number after that the inputed part(from keyboard) of the address skip and jump to the email part. I have attach the output in the bottom. I would be thankful if someone figure out my problem

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class PhoneLibrary {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String contactName;
    double contactNumber;
    String contactAddress;
    String contactEmail;
    String description;
    boolean favourite;

    void fillForm() {
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        contactName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Number: ");
        contactNumber = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Address: ");
        contactAddress = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("E-mail: ");
        contactEmail= input.nextLine();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PhoneLibrary contact = new PhoneLibrary();
        contact.fillForm();
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Name: Vector
Number: 9854425655
Address: E-mail: Vector@gmaail.com
```

Comment: You need to clear buffer , ie. Do a flush. So do input.nextLine() just to reset the scanner before taking input for address

Answer (score 0):

Add `input.nextLine()` after this likes:

```
System.out.print("Number: ");
contactNumber = input.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this before taking input of address.

```
input= new Scanner(System.in);
```

Your code:

```
System.out.print("Name: ");
contactName = input.nextLine();

System.out.print("Number: ");
contactNumber = input.nextDouble();

System.out.print("Address: ");
input= new Scanner(System.in);
contactAddress = input.nextLine();

System.out.print("E-mail: ");
contactEmail= input.nextLine();
```

Comment: thanks it works. but why my previous code not working? It seems like there is no mistake in my previous code.

Comment: Then please approve my answer. yes you don't have any mistake but, you must initialize the scanner object after nextLine() method to take another line of a string

Comment: When you invoke nextLine(), the line is removed from the buffer and effectively discarded from the Scanner. If it helps you please approve the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
System.out.print("Name: ");
contactName = input.nextLine();

System.out.print("Number: ");
contactNumber = Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine());

System.out.print("Address: ");
contactAddress = input.nextLine();

System.out.print("E-mail: ");
contactEmail= input.nextLine();
```

new line was taken in contactAddress in your code as you used nextDouble

Answer (score 0):

use 
input.nextLine(); 
after 
contactNumber = input.nextDouble();

Because nextDouble method does not get return (\r) from console so adress varialble gets the return char and flows to email input

Answer (score -2):

`nextDouble()` is a method of the class Scanner that returns the next scanned double.

have you tried?

```
    void fillForm() {
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        contactName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Number: ");
    try{
        contactNumber = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
    }catch(ParseException e){          
      throw new ParseException();
    }
        System.out.print("Address: ");
        contactAddress = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("E-mail: ");
        contactEmail= input.nextLine();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PhoneLibrary contact = new PhoneLibrary();
        contact.fillForm();
    }
```